# Is there a way to add a timer to specific documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online

More specifically, someone will upload a document and then a timer will start for it. People are able to comment while the timer is still going, but when it is finished, users cannot comment on the document.

Answer (score 0):

If Flow is an option you could create a Flow that waits x number of hours/days and then removes the permissions to edit the document, see https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Is-there-a-way-to-sleep-or-wait-in-a-flow/td-p/18803 for details about the timer part